# Consultar tabla cliente, y sumar saldo de tabla comprobantes

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

mi sonculta es la siguiente:
He realizado dos tablas Clientes y comprobantes, obviamente asociadas por un id_cliente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice una consulta SQL con INNER JOIN, sumando todos los creditos/debitos de comprobantes, para sacar saldo por cliente, pero solo me da un resultado. pero evidentemente algo estoy haciendo mal porque me da el total general de comprobantes.

```
SELECT cliente.*, SUM(comprobantes.credito)-SUM(comprobantes.debito) FROM `cliente` INNER JOIN comprobantes WHERE cliente.id=comprobantes.id_cliente
```

Comment: agrupa por cliente.. si no, solo va a traer una sola fila.. y vos queres una por cliente.. lee sobre group by

Comment: es la solucion!!... ahora me surge un segundo problema, a la resta de credito-debito los llamos saldo (AS saldo), como pongo un filtro por ese valor creado, hago:

Comment: Hago saldo LIKE '%valor%' pero no obtengo resutado

Comment: filtro? que tipo de filtro? like es para cadenas, no numeros..

Comment: Para rangos de números puedes usar, por ejemplo, `saldo BETWEEN 100 AND 500`... Igual te sugiero crear una nueva pregunta para abordar el tema con detalles.